# SQLAlchemy join between dates on two tables. How can I match dates but retain all dates from one column that do not match the other?

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a query so the output gives me all the available dates and a list of empty days where there have been no orders.  I am looking to group these by month and week and some weeks are empty, but I need to return the result from the empty week in order to plot a graph to report it as 0 sales and not just skip it.

I have a list of dates in succession for each day of the year in the Dates table with SQLAlchemy and a list of orders by date and sale price in the Orders table.  I have joined them but I can only somehow return this where it misses out the Dates.day_date where there are no Orders.

| Dates.day_date | Orders.date_created | Orders.sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-01 19:41:17 | 94.8 |
| 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-04 19:21:13 | 24.8 |
| 2021-02-05 | 2021-02-05 13:44:47 | 44.4 |

I am trying to get something like this instead where I keep all the Dates.day_date in the list I have and replace the empty order dates and sales with None or 0:

| Dates.day_date | Orders.date_created | Orders.sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-01 19:41:17 | 94.8 |
| 2021-02-02 | None | None |
| 2021-02-03 | None | None |
| 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-04 19:21:13 | 24.8 |
| 2021-02-05 | 2021-02-05 13:44:47 | 44.4 |

I am working on the following sqlalchemy but I am not getting all the Dates.day_date.  I have tried isouter=True to try and get all the Dates.day_date dates but it doesn't make a difference.

```py
db.session.query(
        Dates.day_date,
        Orders.date_created,
        Orders.sales
    ).select_from(
        Dates
    ).join(
        Orders, Dates.day_date == cast(Orders.date_created, Date)
    ).filter(and_(
        Dates.day_date.between(date_min, date_max),
        Orders.date_created >= date_min,
        Orders.date_created <= date_max,
        Dates.day_date == cast(Orders.date_created, Date)
    )).group_by(
                Orders.date_created,
                Dates.day_date
    ).all()
```

EDIT ---
I have tried .outerjoin() for the left join but it doesn't change.

```py
.outerjoin(
        Dates, Dates.day_date == cast(Orders.date_created, Date)
    )
```

and isouter=True with a normal .join()

```py
.join(
        Dates, Dates.day_date == cast(Orders.date_created, Date), isouter=True
    )
```

but both don't seem to work, does the order of the join or table choice at the start make a difference?

EDIT---
I confused myself because I also had another filter that was causing an error that I didn't have in the example above.  The left outer works fine but now I'm running into an issue with the filter.  I am filtering all the orders from a specific store, but this is causing the issue with the left join.  Any ideas why this is?

```py
.filter(
        Orders.store_id == store.id
)
```

Comment: A common solution is to create a table with a single column that contains all valid dates (often called a "dates table") and then LEFT JOIN that with the other table(s) to ensure that the result set includes all valid dates.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The Dates table I have created is the "dates table" I am trying to connect.  I have used the isouter=True to do a Left Join but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Note that as mentioned in the [version 1.4 tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data.html#outer-and-full-join): "SQL also has a 'RIGHT OUTER JOIN'. SQLAlchemy doesn’t render this directly; instead, reverse the order of the tables and use 'LEFT OUTER JOIN'." So I would expect that you would need to use `.outerjoin(Orders` not `.outerjoin(Dates`

Comment: Thanks once again, appreciate the help, I have it working with .outerjoin(Orders

Comment: I am filtering all the orders from a specific store, but this is causing the issue with the left join. Any ideas why this is?  The Dates table is not related to any store and generic, but as soon as I filter for a specific store it only shows the dates related to those orders and not the dates where there are no orders.

.filter(
        Orders.store_id == store.id
)